How do I update an items description using the Printipy library in Python?
I need to update a products description in Python, but it requires me to specify each element, not just the description. Now, I am getting a 'dict' has no attribute 'to_dict()' error.
Code:
from printipy.api import PrintiPy

# Initialize PrintiPy with your API token and shop ID
api = PrintiPy(api_token='my_token', shop_id='my_shop_id')

# Retrieve the existing product details
product_id = 'my_product_id'
product = api.products.get_product(product_id)
# Update the product description while keeping other fields the same
updated_product = {
    "title": product.title,
    "description": "Your new product description",
    "tags": product.tags,
    "print_areas": product.print_areas,
    "variants": product.variants
}

# Send the update request
response = api.products.update_product(product_id, updated_product)

print("Product updated successfully:", response)

Exact error:
mypath\python.exe C:\Users\impre\IdeaProjects\diffusion\main.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mypath\main.py", line 19, in <module>
    response = api.products.update_product(product_id, updated_product)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "mypath\venv\Lib\site-packages\printipy\api.py", line 335, in inner
    return func(ref, *args, **kwargs, shop_id=shop_id)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "mypath\venv\Lib\site-packages\printipy\api.py", line 533, in update_product
    product_information = self._put(update_product_url, data=update_product.to_dict())
                                                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'to_dict'

Process finished with exit code 1

I have already tried solving this problem in many ways, such as trying to name the elements as ""title": product["title"], which gave me a 'not subscriptable' error.
How can I resolve this issue?

According to comments in the library's source code for the update_product method, the second argument should be an UpdateProduct object, which you can get from your dict as follows:
product = api.products.update_product(
    product_id=product_id,
    update_product=UpdateProduct.from_dict(updated_product),
)

Make sure to add from printipy.data_objects import UpdateProduct to get that datatype imported.

Do you mind sharing your implementation of this logic?

I tried this and got this error:   File "mypath\venv\Lib\site-packages\dataclasses_json\core.py", line 151, in _decode_dataclass
kvs = {decode_names.get(k, k): v for k, v in kvs.items()}
^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'ProductVariant' object has no attribute 'items'
Process finished with exit code 1
my code is:
product = api.products.update_product(
product_id=product_id,
update_product=UpdateProduct.from_dict(updated_product),
)
